# how to constrain solution to joint parameter space using constrOptim in R?

Tags: r, constraints, mathematical-optimization

Here is some fake data and code to minimize a function subject to the constraint that the parameter-wise solutions must lie within the bounds of each parameter's range.  But how would I specify constraints to ensure that the solution lies within the bounds of the observed joint parameter space?  In the example below, the cross gets drawn at the solution, which is clearly outside of the joint parameter space.

```
x =(rnorm(1000))
y = (rnorm(1000))
z = sqrt(exp(x)+exp(y))
plot(x,y,pch=19,col=z)
theta = c(.5,.5)
ui = rbind(
        c(1,0)
    ,   c(-1,0)
    ,   c(0,1)
    ,   c(0,-1)
    )
ci = c(
        min(x)
    ,   -max(x)
    ,   min(y)
    ,   -max(y)
    )
f = function(theta){
    x = theta[1]; y=theta[2]
    sqrt(exp(x)+exp(y))
    }
f(theta)
o = constrOptim(theta,f,control=list(fnscale=1),ci = ci,ui=ui,grad=NULL)
plot(x,y,pch=19,col=z)
points(o$par[1],o$par[2],cex=5,pch=3)
```

[image: joint parameter space]

Comment: As far as I can see, the optimum falls within your parameter space. The cross is drawn at the extreme coordinates. In every run I tried. BTW. you should use set.seed() for reproducibility.

Comment: The joint parameter space.  Which is to say the space where both have been observed.  x has been observed at the left, y has been observed at the bottom, but never has x,y been observed at the lower left.

Comment: I think you should look more carefully at the plots. Print `o` and calculate `ui %*% o$par - ci`. The result satisfies the constraints you have imposed; `constrOptim` goes to the boundaries. If this is not what you want, then tell us in more detail what exactly you want.

Comment: I want to know how to set constraints so that the solution lies in the joint parameter space.  The constraints I specified don't do that, they are an example of getting an answer I don't want.  I don't know how to get the answer I want.  I would be grateful if someone who has solved this problem before could help.  I've been fiddling with pencil and paper math, but all of my solutions seem to require iterative changing of the constraints based on parameter values at a given step, which is both expensive and not compatible with consrtOptim.  Maybe there is some clever math that does it?

Comment: Did you check what you're actually trying to do? Your objective function, `sqrt(exp(x) + exp(y))`, is monotonically increasing in both x and y. So naturally when you try to minimise it, which is what `constrOptim` does, you're going to end up with a solution that sets x and y to the minimum possible.

Comment: None of these comments understand the purpose of the example.  I want to specify constraints on the solution such that the answer falls on a polygon on a plane defined by the joint extent of x and y.

Comment: In my real application, the objective function is an uncertain approxomation and I do not want to make out-of-sample predictions about the optimum.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean by "joint parameter space".

If you mean "the points in the plot", that is a finite set of points:
you have a discrete optimization problem.
You can evaluate `f` at all the points and take the minimum with `which.min`.

```
d <- cbind(x,y)[ z >= 1, ]
i <- which.min( apply(d, 1, f) )
points( d[i,,drop=FALSE], pch=3, cex=3 )
```

But if you want to use your points to define a connected area of the plane,
there is no unique way to do so.
The convex hull is the most obvious choice, but your plot suggests a non-convex area -- and
`constrOptim` cannot deal with non-convex constraints.

Comment: Its not a discrete optimization problem.  Rather I want to rule out solutions that are not in the 5-dimensional polygon defined by the limits of my actual dataset.  I guess what you're saying is that I'd need to define a polygon based on my 5-d cloud of points, and that polygon couldn't have any "dimples" (non-convexities), which in fact it does.